# Meteor: insert template between other templates and transfer data between templates

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor for creating web application. I have defined my layout is:

```
<template name="default_layout">
   {{> header}}
   body code here
   {{> footer}}
</template>
```

And here is my routing file:

```
Router.configure({ layoutTemplate: 'default_layout'
});
Router.map(function() { this.route('post_list', {path: '/'});
});
```

So. I have two questions:

1. How to make template `post_list` go into body code of `default_layout` template ?
2. Base on each layout for mapping page, maybe header and footer change content respectively. So, how to contact between template? For example, `post_list` template will set some value for `header` template ...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the {{> yield}} helper. This will insert whatever template your route is serving. So.

   ```
   <template name="default_layout">
      {{> header}}
      {{> yield}}
      {{> footer}}
   </template>
   ```
2. If you want to change what goes into the header, you will be using "yield regions.

   ```
   <template name="default_layout">
      {{> yield "header"}}
      {{> yield
      {{> yield "footer"}}
   </template>
   ```

   Then, in, say, a route controll you could do this:

   ```
   PostController = RouteController.extend({
        yieldRegions: {
            'postHeader': {to: 'header'},
            'postFooter': {to: 'footer'}
        }
    })
   ```

   Then in your post_list route, do this:

   ```
   Router.route('post_list', function(){
       controller: 'postController'
   });
   ```

   Basically, you are creating a controller that can be re-used for certain routes, and telling the controller to put a template called "postHeader" into the {{> yield "header"}} region and "postFooter" into the {{> yield "footer"}} region.

Comment: So. we will create `postHeader` `answerHeader` ... base on our purpose, right ? And normally, where will we put `PostController = RouteController.extend ...` ? Same file with `Route.route` or should on different file. ? thanks :)

Comment: You can use separate files for your routing logic if you want, but they should all be in a folder called "lib" which makes them available on both the server and client. Or, you can just throw them all in one "router.js" file inside the lib folder. The first is probably a better option.

Comment: for example, you could have a "postRoutes.js" file and inside you would have a PostController and your Router.route('post_list', function()) route as well.